# How to get latest google fit params in one api call

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk, google-fit-api, google-fitness-api

I need to fetch multiple params from google fit like "Heart Rate", "Body Temperature" etc... But looks like there is no single api to fetch all of them.
There is this one api called dataset aggregate, shown below, we can pass multiple params for get, (like heart rate, body temperature. but this is returning only the aggregate values like "Max Heart Rate", "Min Heart Rate", "Average Heart Rate", "Max Body Temperature" in the specified time frame. but not the heart rate, body temperature.
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/userId/dataset:aggregate

Is there any i can fetch the latest values for multiple params, the below api fetches the latest value but only one param can be passed at a time.

https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/userId/dataSources/dataSourceId

kindly let me know if there's any way i can fetch multiple params from a single api,
thanks in advance. through rest api

Answer (score 0):

This works as intended. Only one data source at a time can be queried for information. Additionally, retrieving data depends on the API call via the dataSourceID.